# Dificuldade para definir o path onde determinado txt será criado

Tags: java

O método abaixo gera um txt contendo determinada informação:

```
public static void gravarIp(String ip)
{   
    try {
        File arquivo = new File("ip.txt");  
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);  
        String texto = ip;  
        fos.write(texto.getBytes());  
        fos.close();
        atualizarPortal(ip);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Porém, este txt está sendo gerado no local onde a instrução é executada:

```
c:\>java -cp c:\users\fabio\desktop EnviarIp
```

Ou seja, se a instrução acima for executada e eu estiver na raiz do c: o txt será gerado lá. Como faço para gerar o txt na mesma raiz na qual está o arquivo EnviarIp sem precisar especificar o caminho absoluto no código fonte?

Comment: Primeiro, o que é `EnviarIp`? Nada no código indica isto. Seguindo, porque não pode especificar o caminho absoluto?

Comment: Publiquei apenas parte do código, "EnviarIP" é a classe java, como já deve ser de conhecimento para executar um código java podemos utilizar a linha de comando java -cp caminho_do_arquivo Arquivo. Não posso informar o caminho pois ele será relativo conforme a profile de usuário e demais fatores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O máximo que consegui foi gerar um arquivo em um local fixo como a pasta de Usuário (pode ser uma subpasta dentro dela se desejar) ou um Caminho absoluto como disco C:, pasta Arquivos de Programas etc.

Fica assim:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {       
            File arquivo = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "ip.txt");  
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);  
            String texto = "192.168.1.1";  
            fos.write(texto.getBytes());  
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Infelizmente não consegui gerar o arquivo no mesmo local da classe/jar.

---

Resposta encontrada com a ajuda do próprio usuário da pergunta:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            String diretorio = System.getProperty("user.dir");      
            File arquivo = new File(diretorio, "ip.txt");  
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);  
            String texto = "192.168.1.1";  
            fos.write(texto.getBytes());  
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/FilePath.java).

Pesquisando a propriedade `System.getProperty("user.dir")` é o diretório onde está a classe. Desculpa por não ter descoberto antes e agradeço.

Fonte: [System Properties - Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: Caro amigo agradeço vossa ajuda, consegui resolver o problema fazendo assim: "String diretorio = System.getProperty("user.dir");" e depois informando essa variável como parte do caminho. Isso considerando o exemplo que você passou :)

Comment: É isso mesmo, não sei como não vi isso antes. Segue a resposta editada. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser o caminho corrente e não um fixo:

```
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/GetCanonicalPath.java).